# Pandas - create dataframe manually and insert values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, manual

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A", "B"])
df.iloc[0]['A'] = 5
```

Here is output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/Dop/Pentas/Simpletest/Temp.py", line 38, in <module>
    df.iloc[0]['A'] = 5
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1189, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1480, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 89, in _get_loc
    return self.obj._ixs(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1719, in _ixs
    label = self.index[i]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1076, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it? I do not know overall size of my dataframe before hand, but I can guess.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either initialize dataframe with data using

`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"], data=[[5,np.nan]])`,

or use `set_value` method (which is much faster than `iloc` by the way):
`df.set_value(0,'A',5)`

**UPDATE 2018-04-12** ⬇

Since pandas version 0.21.0 `df.set_value` is deprecated. You should use `.at[]`or `.iat[]` accessors instead:

```
df.at[0, 'A'] = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Providing a sample to increase your data frame dynamically... sizeOfDataFrame variable just limits for loop which adds data to the dataframe and is dynamic...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
yourDataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
sizeOfDataFrame = np.random.randint(100, size=1)
for currentLine in range(sizeOfDataFrame):
    yourDataFrame = yourDataFrame.append(pd.DataFrame({"A":np.random.randint(100, size=1),"B":np.random.randint(100, size=1),"C":np.random.randint(100, size=1)},index=[0]))
yourDataFrame.reset_index(inplace = True)    
yourDataFrame.drop('index',axis=1,inplace=True)
```